# parsing a string in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am wanting to parse a string within SQL, However, I am not sure how to go about doing so.

Here is my code:

```
 SELECT distinct sku, A_CLUSTER_DESC 
 FROM TOOL_SAS_DATA 
 WHERE sku in (1099895,
  1099896,
  1000960,
  1000960,
  1000898
  );
```

My output is:

```
  ||  sku  || A_Cluster_desc   ||

1 ||1099895|| 'GG SAS AP_1234 A'||

2 ||1099896|| 'GG SAS AP_1113 B'||
```

etc.

I am wanting to just output under `A_Cluster_desc`
for it to say `AP_1234` or `AP_1113` and just excluding everything else around it.

EDIT:

Sorry if it wasn't more clear, I am wanting to just output AP_1234 or AP_####

Comment: Is it always going to be of the same pattern like AP_1234 including the prefix and suffix?

Comment: It will always say AP_ with 4 numbers following it

Comment: you need ues `regexp_substr()` and regular expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for `A_CLUSTER_DESC` part, use :

```
select regexp_substr(A_CLUSTER_DESC, '(.*?GG SAS )(.*?) ',1,1,'',2) from TOOL_SAS_DATA;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9108e2/1)